# Hiding an <li> element in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, dom

I need your help

If `document.getElementById("file").children[1].style.display = "none";` hides the "Save" item in the "file" menu, then `document.getElementById("edit").children[1].style.display = "none";` does not work properly and does not hide the "Add new" item in the "edit" menu item.

```
<div id="menuwrapper">
    <div id="menu" style="width: 1001px; height: 20px">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#nogo"><div id="div_rssims_file">File</div></a>

                <ul id="file">
                    <li><a onclick="window.print()"><div id="div_rssims_file_print">Print</div></a></li>
                    <li id="li_rssims_file_save"><a onclick="rssims_save()"><div id="div_rssims_file_save">Save</div></a></li>
                    <li><a onclick="rssims_save();window.close()"><div id="div_rssims_file_save_exit">Save & Exit</div></a></li>
                    <li><a onclick="window.close()"><div id="div_rssims_file_exit">Exit</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#nogo"><div id="div_rssims_edit">Edit</div></a>

                <ul id="edit">
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="rssims_addnew()"><div id="div_rssims_edit_addnew">Add new</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_delete()"><div id="delete">Delete</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_reset()"><div id="clear">Clear Form</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#nogo"><div id="div_rssims_view">View</div></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_first">&gt;&gt; Go to First</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_next">&gt;Go to Next</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_prev">Go to Previous&gt;</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_last">Go to Last&gt;&gt;</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#nogo"><div id="div_rssims_reports">Reports</div></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="export_excel">Export to Excel Table</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_compile_htmltable()"><div id="export_html">Export to HTML Table</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_compile_htmllist()"><div id="export_list">Export to HTML List</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_compile_contactcard()"><div id="export_contact">Export as Contact Card</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="sims_logoff()"><div id="div_rssims_logoff">Logoff</div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the issue, but `document.getElementById("edit").children[1]` is the "Delete" option, not the "Add new" option.  "Add new" would be `document.getElementById("edit").children[0]`.

Comment: Probably should be `document.getElementById("edit").children[0].style.display = "none" //Add new`

Comment: Which menu item are you trying to hide? If you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/RfW84/ it hides the Save item in the File list and the Delete item in the Edit list. You can change which item by changing the index you select in `children`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("edit").children[0].style.display = "none"
```

Add New is a first position of #edit

Answer (score 1):

You're not deleting the right item, because `[1]` will select the **second** child. To grab the first one, use `[0]` instead:

```
document.getElementById("edit").children[1].style.display = "none"
```

That this works for the first example given is probably because it **is** the second element.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("file").children[1].style.display = "none";
```

Is hiding the 'Save' menu item (the 2nd child of `<ul id="file">`).

```
document.getElementById("edit").children[1].style.display = "none";
```

Is hiding the 'Delete' menu item (the 2nd child of `<ul id="edit">`).

If you want to hide the 'Add New' submenu item, you should target the first child of `<ul id="edit">` like this:

```
document.getElementById("edit").children[0].style.display = "none";
```

If you want to hide the entire 'Edit' submenu with all items, you should target the `<ul id="edit">` like this:

```
document.getElementById("edit").style.display = "none";
```

This does point out an important drawback of using `children` as a means of selecting menu items. If the order of the items changes, so does your Javascript.

You are much better off targeting the items by their `class`names or `id`s. If you remove the inner `div` from the `a` link in each item (this is superfluous), and replace the `id` on the `li` element, you can target just the menu item you want:

```
            <ul id="edit">
                <li id="div_rssims_edit_addnew"><a href="#nogo" onclick="rssims_addnew()">Add new</a></li>
                <li id="delete"><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_delete()">Delete</a></li>
                <li id="clear"><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_reset()">Clear Form</a></li>
            </ul>

document.getElementById("div_rssims_edit_addnew").style.display = "none";
```

This always works, no matter what the order of the items is. It still blows up with an error if the element(s) are not present in the page. To prevent this, you best use a javascript library like jQuery to do this: http://api.jquery.com/hide/.